# Node Server Unable to Start

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, express, npm

**Issue**: Unable to start Node server

**Platform**: Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10

Currently following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_1-Kge54K4&app=desktop) that builds a blog on MEAN

Commands ran after installation:

```
apt-get install npm
npm init
npm install express --save
node server.js
```

Last command `node server.js` supposed to start Node server.

But nothing happens on my bash command line.
[image]

```
server.js codes:
```

[image]

```
command node-v (node version not found):
```

[image]

```
However, Node is already installed:
```

[image]

```
Accessing localhost:3000
```

[image]

Comment: You check your code in server.js? Does it have anything to execute? From what i see it may be empty..Hope this helps.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk I have updated my post with the screenshot of my server.js. Hope it helps

Comment: try console.log('something');

Comment: i added console.log('something'); in server.js. No results shown in bash command line too.

Comment: Do you try to go into localhost:3000? what does it say? If cannot get. Then server works fine. If site cant be reachable then it's something else.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk I was unable to access localhost:3000 due to Site Can't Be Reached. I have attached a few more screenshots. There seems to be a problem with NodeJS. I was unable to locate the node version. But node is already installed.

Comment: Update: Manually installed Node.js via Nodejs website too. No results.

Comment: @gymcode Did you run `sudo apt-get purge node npm` before installing Node.js from the website? FWIW, `apt-get node` doesn't install Node.js (different program by the same name).

Comment: I've tested it here and it doesn't even execute the first line, so I'm guessing it's not a problem with express. @gymcode you might want to include `strace` information.

Comment: @SamirAguiar how can I include strace information?

Comment: @RyanZim nope I did not run the command before installing node.js from the website. should I uninstall node.js from control panal, and run the purge command, and try to install from the website again?

Comment: On Ubuntu the package is called `nodejs`, not `node`: `sudo apt-get install nodejs` (and I think that the executable is also called that: `nodejs server.js`)

Comment: @robertklep I tried the command, but it was reflected that nodejs is already installed to the latest version. no changes were made too.

Comment: @gymcode I updated by comment, see the part about the name of the executable as well.

Comment: @robertklep I wouldn't advise installing nodejs with `apt`. The version is outdated, and the executable name requires symlinking to get shebangs to work.

Comment: @RyanZim yeah I was just writing an answer to reflect that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu (and Debian as well), the correct package to install for Node.js is called `nodejs`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

However, my experience is that this generally installs an outdated version of Node, which isn't great. It also installs the interpreter with the executable name `nodejs`, not `node` as you would expect.

Alternatively, you can add the official binary distribution repositories for Node.js, which allows you to install more recent versions of Node (v6 or even v7). These are also kept up-to-date much better than the Ubuntu/Debian repositories.

The process is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions), but if you want to install Node v6, you would run this code:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

It's probably best to remove any previously installed packages (`npm`, `node`, `nodejs`) before running the commands above.